# Receive delimited Protobuf message in python via TCP

Tags: python, sockets, protocol-buffers

I am trying to receive a protobuf message, which was send from a java application with "writeDelmitedTo()" inside my python application.

After some research I already came across this code to read the message from the socket, decode it and parse it.

```
data = sock.recv()
(size, position) = decoder._DecodeVarint(data, 0)
msg = MessageWrapper_pb2.WrapperMessage().ParseFromString(data[position:position + size])
```

What I am getting now is a google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message Exception.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or knows how to read delimited data from a socket and parse it correctly?

**Edit:**

This is the solution that worked for me.

```
def read_java_varint_delimited_stream(sock):
    buf = []
    data = sock.recv()
    rCount = len(data)
    (size, position) = decoder._DecodeVarint(data, 0)

    buf.append(data)
    while rCount < size+position:
        data = sock.recv(size+position-rCount)
        rCount += len(data)
        buf.append(data)

    return b''.join(buf), size, position

def readMessage(sock):
    data, size, position = read_java_varint_delimited_stream(sock)
    msg = MessageWrapper_pb2.WrapperMessage()
    msg.ParseFromString(data[position:position + size])

    return msg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream protocol and there is nothing that says a `recv` on one end is paired with a single `send` on the other end. Message based protocols need some way to mark their boundaries so the receiver knows how to find message boundaries.

The [writeDelimitedTo docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite.html#writeDelimitedTo-java.io.OutputStream-) say that a `varint` size is sent and then the data. So, read the `varint` and then read that number of bytes.

Digging deeper, the [varint docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) describe how its value is encoded by using a byte's high-bit to mark continuation. We we can write up our own decoder

```
import struct

def read_java_varint_delimited_stream(sock):
    sz = 0
    while True:
        vbyte, = struct.unpack('b', sock.recv(1))
        sz = (vbyte << 7) + (vbyte & 0x7f)
        if not vbyte & 0x80:
            break
    data = []
    while sz:
        buf = sock.recv(sz)
        if not buf:
            raise ValueError("Buffer receive truncated")
        data.append(buf)
        sz -= len(buf)
    return b''.join(buf)
```

Comment: There was something wrong with the calculated size, which was always way to large so the loop would never end. I slightly modified the function (see above).